# IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: No module named os

Tags: c#, .net, ironpython

Im using IronPython on C#.Net 3.5 app with VS 2015.
I read all the post about this Topic, but still get this error. my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        var searchPaths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
        searchPaths.Add(@"C:\myProject\packages\DynamicLanguageRuntime.1.1.2");
        searchPaths.Add(@"C:\myProject\packages\IronPython.2.7.7\lib");
        searchPaths.Add(@"C:\myProject");
        searchPaths.Add(@"C:\myProject\"where myfile.py exists");
        engine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);
        var mainfile = @"C:\myProject\myfile.py";
        var scope = engine.CreateScope();
        engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(mainfile).Execute(scope);
        var result = scope.GetVariable("res");
       // Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

and myfile.py start with :

```
import os
import csv
import unirest
     .
     .
res = "something"
```

Does someone knows what can be the problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

My problem fixed. I needed to download python 2.7.13 and then change the line:

```
searchPaths.Add(@"C:\myProject\packages\IronPython.2.7.7\lib");
```

to line:

```
searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Python27\Lib");
```